# Borrar todos los datos de una tabla

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hola estoy tratando de borrar todos los datos de una tabla en `mysql` con un boton desde mi proyecto `laravel`, lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente manera pero no me funciona, me sale `pagina expirada`, el codigo de mi controlador es el siguiente.

```
public function borrarDatos(){
      $marca=tbl_marca::all();
      $marca->delete();
      return back()->with('success', 'Datos Borrados Satisfactoriamente.'); 
    }
```

En mi vista tengo lo siguiente

```
    <form action="{{ route('borrar') }}" class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Eliminar Datos</button>
   </form>
```

Y mi ruta es la siguiente

```
Route::post('EliminarDatos', 'TestController@borrarDatos')->name('borrar');
```

Como podria solucionarlo? gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

como bien te han dicho necesitas el token @csrf, tu codigo quedaria asi:

```
<form action="{{ route('borrar') }}" class="form-horizontal" 
    method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
 <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">EliminarDatos</button>
</form>
```

## **Edito:**

Otra manera de hacerlo y mas rapida:

```
DB::table('tuTabla')->delete();
```

Yo haria un check con un `->first()`, para ver si hay datos en la tabla antes de hacer el `->delete()`:

```
$check = tbl_marca::first();
  if(! $check == null){
     $marca=tbl_marca::all();
     foreach($marca as $mar){
        $mar->delete();
     }
      return Response::json(array(
            'succes' => true,
            'errors' => ' Datos Borrados Satisfactoriamente. '
        ), 200);
  }else{
       return Response::json(array(
            'succes' => false,
            'errors' => ' No hay datos que borrar. '
        ), 400);
   }
```

Es una de las formas de hacerlo, como todo hay muchas más, para mi lo mas sencillo.
Espero que te sirva

Comment: Si quiero eliminar en ese boton otros registros de otra tabla haría lo mismo de nuevo pero con otra tabla no?

Comment: Asi es, utilizas el model que quieras eliminar

Answer (score 2):

Hace falta el **`token`** que de por confiable está acción, eso lo resuelves con:

```
@csrf
```

Justo después de la etiqueta form de apertura

Por cierto la consulta de eliminación se puede reducir a

```
tbl_marca::query()->delete();
```

**Referencias**

- [csrf token](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token)